# Image compression takes too long on Flutter Web

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I tried to compress web image using the below code (with image_compression_flutter package), however it takes about 1 minute to compress a 6 mb image.

```
Future<Uint8List?> compressImage(Uint8List imgBytes,
    {required String path, int quality = 70}) async {
 final input = ImageFile(
    rawBytes: imgBytes,
    filePath: path,
  );
  Configuration config = Configuration(
    outputType: ImageOutputType.jpg,
    // can only be true for Android and iOS while using ImageOutputType.jpg or ImageOutputType.pngÏ
    useJpgPngNativeCompressor: false,
    // set quality between 0-100
    quality: quality,
  );
  final param = ImageFileConfiguration(input: input, config: config);
  final output = await compressor.compress(param);
  return output.rawBytes;
}
```

Is it because of web limitations it takes such a long time to compress?
Is there any workaround regarding this issue

Comment: Have you tried it on non-web? How long does it take?

Comment: @user1032613 I didn't try it on non-web, because I used another package(image_picker) for Android OS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eventually, I found a solution for compressing web image. Image picker now has XFile type which can be directly compressed in web. It took about 2 seconds to compress a 12mb image to 50kb

```
 final XFile? pickedImageFile = await ImagePicker().pickImage(
    source: isCamera ? ImageSource.camera : ImageSource.gallery,
    imageQuality: imageQuality,
    maxWidth: maxWidth,
    preferredCameraDevice: CameraDevice.rear);
```

While uploading to a server there is no need to convert XFile to any type. Just need to read bytes from pickedImageFile

```
   await pickedImageFile.readAsBytes();
```